# TvirtualStringTree custom color for nodes levels ( column and row )

Tags: delphi, tvirtualstringtree

I have TVirtualStringTree and I want to change its nodes background color based on the nodes levels as this picture :

[image]

I have tried like this but its giving my desired result for the rows only:

```
procedure TForm1.VSTBeforeCellPaint(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
  CellPaintMode: TVTCellPaintMode; CellRect: TRect; var ContentRect: TRect);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  if CellPaintMode = cpmPaint then
  begin
    R := Sender.GetDisplayRect(Node, Column, True, False, True);
    R.Offset(0, -R.Top);
    case Sender.GetNodeLevel(Node) of
      0: TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $0000F9FF;
      1: TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $0000BFFF;
      2: TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $000086FF;
    end;
    TargetCanvas.FillRect(CellRect);
  end;

end;
```

Comment: In your picture you show only a case where different levels are not "crossing". You also need to consider e.g. that you have a third level (yellow) item under the 5th line ("GS-01 Users...."). How would you want to paint the crossover with level 2 (green lines) at e.g. row 10 ("Report Group: Resources")? Green on Yellow or vv.? What if you have a fourth level (with say, red color)? would you want the vertical colored line to show under the icons at all lines below? What about further levels?

Comment: This will depend in the node data itself , e.g. If the `NodeData.Is_Activity` then the row & the Col will be white background otherwise it will be from my color list , the example that I attached shows the color for the levels but it didn't take by consideration the Col level .

Comment: The bg color of the items is not a problem, as you already know. My question is **what do you want to do with a vertical colored line, when that line goes through the text of other items down the list**. You need to be precise, and cover all possible situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if its totally correct but its giving good result :

```
procedure VSTBeforeCellPaint(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
  CellPaintMode: TVTCellPaintMode; CellRect: TRect; var ContentRect: TRect);
var
  R: TRect;
  RectArr:Array of TRect;
  NodeLevel,i,k:Integer;
  ArrayColors:Array[0..6] of Tcolor ;
begin
 NodeLevel:=Sender.GetNodeLevel(Node);
  if CellPaintMode = cpmPaint then
  begin
  if Column=0 then
   begin
    R := CellRect;

    setlength(RectArr,NodeLevel+2);
    RectArr[Length(RectArr)-1]:=Rect(r.Left+node.NodeHeight*(NodeLevel+1)-Node.NodeHeight,r.Top,r.Right,r.Bottom);
    for i := 0 to Length(RectArr)-2 do
    RectArr[i]:=Rect(r.Left+Node.NodeHeight*(i-1),r.Top,r.Left+Node.NodeHeight*i+Node.NodeHeight,r.Bottom);
      ArrayColors[0]:= $0000F9FF;
      ArrayColors[1] := $0000BFFF;
      ArrayColors[2]:= $000086FF;
      ArrayColors[3] := ClLime;
      ArrayColors[4] := Clred;
      ArrayColors[5] := clSkyBlue;
      ArrayColors[6]:= clGrayText;

    for I := 0 to Length(RectArr)-1 do
    begin
    K:=i-1;
    if k<0 then    k:=0;

    TargetCanvas.Brush.Color:=ArrayColors[k];
    TargetCanvas.FillRect(RectArr[i]);
    end;
   end else
       begin
       case Sender.GetNodeLevel(Node) of
       0: TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $0000F9FF;
       1: TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $0000BFFF;
       2: TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $000086FF;
       3:TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := ClLime;
       4:TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := Clred;
       5:TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := clSkyBlue ;
       6:TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := clGrayText ;
       end;
       TargetCanvas.FillRect(CellRect);
       end;
  end;

end;
```

The Result :
[image]